# EJB invocations from a remote server instance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have created two EARs a1.ear and a2.ear. These two EARs are deployed on WildFly server S1 and S2.

S1 and S2 servers are on different machines having different IP addresses.

Wildfly server S1 => a1.ear, a2.ear

Wildfly server S2 => a1.ear, a2.ear

In S1:
a1.ear has exposed certain objects and a2.ear looks up that remote object of a1.ear and it successfully gets the object. It always gets the object from a1.ear deployed on S1 server.
I need remote object deployed on S2 server. Please let me know how to get it.

I have followed the steps mentioned in the following article:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance

Please help.

Comment: Which exception is thrown when you try to invoke the remote object?

Comment: There is no exception. 
Let's say in server S1, a2.ear invokes the remote object and it gets the object from a1.ear deployed on server S1. But I want the remote object that is deployed on S2 server.

Comment: you need provide to the InitialContext instace (the one used to look up the remote object) the remote server ip and port